# Does IntelliJ packs "test file" along with the application in APK

Tags: android, unit-testing, intellij-idea, apk, robolectric

I am trying to write Unit test for an Android application in IntelliJ Idea (which is a wonderful IDE) using Robolectric. I have created unit test in the same application as suggested in [this blog](http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2012/08/integrating-robolectric-with-intellij.html#comment-form).

Now my question does IntelliJ IDE pack the test classes also along with the application classes in the final APK?

Comment: It will great pleasure to know why the question has been downvoted.

Comment: I don't know but I upvoted you to even it out :)

Comment: @justeric Thanks, I started doubting I made some mistake but you helped.

Comment: No prob. Sometimes people browse questions real fast and accidentally vote on something. Interesting question though, I'll be looking forward to the answer too. I thought about switching to IntelliJ a couple times but I never took the dive.

Comment: @justeric Take it and you will thank me. IntelliJ is awesome and free.

Comment: Its a rough dive especially being new to maven too.  Eclipse has some easier things but Intellij does a few things better.  Git for one thing it handles really well, I always had to fight Eclipse with GIT when merging conflicts or switching branches.  Upvoted as I need to know this answer too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android Facet has the corresponding setting:

[image: Include test code and resources into APK]